# Android - Get an image picked from a camera into a photo gallery

Tags: android, image, camera

I am new to Android.  This is my first question. I am testing on 4.4.4, KitKat.

I am using the Android Developers "Taking Photos Simply" code in my app.
([Taking Photos Simply Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html))
I want the photos taken by the user to be available to my app, but also available later in the gallery.

If I specify

```
File storageDir =  getExternalFilesDir (null);
```

Then various cameras work (camera, opencamera, DSLR camera), but after I leave my app the images do not appear in the gallery.

If I specify

```
File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

Then the behavior is the same, except for one camera app: DSLR Camera.  The photo does appear in that app's camera directory which is visible using the gallery later.

I want this behavior for my app.  I want the photos that the user takes to appear in a directory that they can later see using the gallery app. I don't want to create duplicate images, however.

I also want to save modified images later on to the same directory.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Do not specicy a storage dir to begin with. The camera app will store then to .../DCIM/Camera. Both Gallery app and your app have access to that location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but after I leave my app the images do not appear in the gallery.

It may eventually. Gallery apps usually use the `MediaStore`, and your file may eventually be added to it. Use `MediaScannerConnection` and `scanFile()` to expedite this process.

Comment: This worked.  If the user takes a picture i want it to show up in the gallery immediately so that if the user then decides to pick it from the gallery they will find it there.  running the mediaScanIntent would not do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the media scanner to scan a file and add it to the media database.Use this code.

```
 Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            mediaScanIntent.setData(mMediaUri);
            sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```

and see  [ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE)  in android developer site.Here **mMediaUri** is the Uri of your file.